# Android - Notepad as database storage

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, notepad

I've been given a database of english words but they're in a .txt file. not an sql file.
My professor told me I could use it as database for my dictionary application instead of using sqlite.

Can anybody please give me any idea how to access the notepad?

I need to compare an inputWord to the notepad files and if found, it will copy the definition of the inputWord from the notepad and display it onscreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad files have UTF-8 Text String stored in them, what you will have to do is to read the whole file, parse the keywords and their definitions , and then search for any keyword in the list.
a pseudocode for that would look like this:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("the_file_name");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
do  {
         line = br.readLine();
         builder.append(line);
 } while (line != null);
 parseFile(builder.toString);



 public void parseFile(String txt){
.......  code to parse the txt from file and pass it to variables to use in the comparison
```

}